# Cannot add MemberSubstitution using Bytebuddy

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I'm trying to add a `MemberSubstitution` using ByteBuddy to intercept any access to a specific field, but when running the following code I get this error: `Could not resolve com.test.MyClass$ByteBuddy$PdQdmF1w using net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$ClassLoading@5e712ea6`

```
final var bytebuddy = new ByteBuddy();
var instrumentedType =
    bytebuddy
        .subclass(MyClass.class)
        .method(ElementMatchers.any())
        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MethodInterceptor.class))
        .visit(MemberSubstitution.strict()
            .field(ElementMatchers.named("fieldName"))
            .onRead()
            .stub()
            .on(ElementMatchers.any()))
        .make()
        .load(MyClass.class.getClassLoader())
        .getLoaded();
```

If I remove the call to the `visit` method, everything works as expected (every method call gets intercepted).

On the contrary, if I retain only the call to the `visit` method, I get no exception, but the substitution does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `MemberSubstitution.relaxed()`. There is a generated type without manifest byte code that the substitution struggles to resolve. Therefore, the relaxed resolution can simply skip those types.

Comment: If I use `relaxed` instead of `strict` I get no exception, but the substitution does not seem to work (if I invoke a method that reads the field `fieldName` I still see its original value instead of the stubbed one).